# How to Read System.GUID on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's my controller action

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetOrderNum(String input)
{
    AEntities db = new AEntities();

    var result = from r in db.orders
                 where r.TrackingNumber.ToString() == input
                 select new {
                     r.Status,                          
                 };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And here I make the AJAX call

```
var myActionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetTrackingNumber", "ACustomer")';
    var trackingInfo = $('#TrackingNumber').val();

     $('.Track').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: myActionUrl,
                data: $('#TrackingNumber').val(),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (json) {
                    alert("Response as JS Object: " + json);
                    console.log(json);
                }
      });
```

the problem is that it wont read the `r.TrackingNumber.ToString()` as it is `system.guid`. Any idea how I can resolve this?

At the moment when I run it, I just get an empty array `"[]"`.

Comment: What do you mean, "it won't read" `r.TrackingNumber.ToString()`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways that a GUID can be represented as a string.

System.Guid.ToString() provides an [overload with a format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Select a format specifier that matches the format of the GUID found in `input`.

**UPDATE**

> 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

You will need to instead create a GUID from `input`:

```
Guid inputGuid = Guid.Parse(input);

var result = from r in db.orders
             where r.TrackingNumber == inputGuid
             select new {
                 r.Status,                          
             };
```

Comment: I tried that and it came up with this error:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method `public JsonResult GetOrderNum(String input)` to read `public JsonResult GetOrderNum(Guid input)` thus passing the parameter as a GUID.  Then there is no need to convert the data store GUID.

Answer (score 0):

```
       function FunctionName(Input) {  
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/GetOrderNum?Input=' + Input=', // Your URL Here
           data: $('#TrackingNumber').val(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                alert("Response as JS Object: " + json);
                console.log(json);
            }
      });
 }

  [HttpGet]
   public JsonResult GetOrderNum()
   {

      string input =HttpContext.Current.Request["Input"].ToString();              
      Guid input= Guid.Parse(input);
      AEntities db = new AEntities();

             var result = from r in db.orders
             where r.TrackingNumber.ToString() == input
             select new {
                 r.Status,                          
             };

          return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          }
```